# How do I match a group of text under a title that changes

Tags: regex

New to this regex and everyone here has been an awesome resource for help but I’m running up against the wall and no matter what I cant see to get the grouping to work.

I’m looking to match the name of the room and the products and services that belong to that room. The number of rooms can vary same with the names, the description of the product or service may change but the line will always start with “Product” or “Service”.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be truly appreciated.

> ```
> Master Bedroom
> Product description of the product
> Product description of the product
> Service description of the service
> Kitchen
> Product description of the product
> Services description of the service
> ```

Comment: ^(Product).(.*?)$ and ^(Services).(.*?)$

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get better results if you can use a regex alongside a bit of postprocessing. For example, the following regex will match all of the service/product lines:

```
(Product|Service[s]?)(.*)
```

But you will still need to get the name of the header. You could perhaps start with something like this:

```
(.*)\n((Product|Service[s]?)(.*)\n)+
```

In which case your capturing groups will include the name of the heading and then ALL of the lines in that section; you can then split and process each with the first regex I provided.

If you're able to share which programming language/tool you're using to run this processing, I can help you write the code to split the data correctly from the first regex.

You can look at this regex in action at [regexr](https://regexr.com/4osd8):

For the input string:

```
Master Bedroom
Product Bedknobs, cheap
Product Beautiful carpet polish
Service Free pillow sharpening
Kitchen
Product Sink grease
Services Inexpensive cucumber delivery
```

You will get the following groups:

```
Master Bedroom
Product Bedknobs, cheap
Product Beautiful carpet polish
Service Free pillow sharpening
```

and

```
Kitchen
Product Sink grease
Services Inexpensive cucumber delivery
```

**[edit]** note that this regex WILL capture the "Product/Service" string as its own group... Figured you could always throw it away if you didn't need it, but didn't hurt to have access to it after parsing :)